# C++ Converting binary data to a hex string and back

Tags: c++, visual-studio, string, binary

I have a matching pair of static functions in a utility class that I use to convert between binary data (unsigned characters) and it's string representation (a-f and 0-9). They seemed to work correctly but recently I tried to compile my code under Visual C++ (2010 Express) and to my dismay, they cause nothing but heap corruption errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
void Utility::string_to_binary(const std::string source, unsigned char* destination, unsigned int length)
{
    unsigned int effective_length = min(length, (unsigned int) source.length() / 2);
    for(unsigned int b = 0; b < effective_length; b++)
    {
        sscanf(source.data() + (b * 2), "%02x", (unsigned int*) &destination[b]);
    }
}

void Utility::binary_to_string(const unsigned char* source, unsigned int length, std::string& destination)
{
    destination.clear();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char digit[3];
        sprintf(digit, "%02x", source[i]);
        destination.append(digit);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Here's a complete program that illustrates the problem.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hdcs/Utility.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Generate some data
    unsigned int size = 1024;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size];

    //Convert it to it's string representation
    string hex;
    Utility::binary_to_string(data, size, hex);

    //Output it to the screen
    cout << hex << endl;

    //Clear the data buffer
    memset(data, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * size);

    //Convert the hex string back to binary
    Utility::string_to_binary(hex, data, size);

    //Cleanup
    delete[] data;
}
```

The error occurs on `delete[] data`.

Comment: Well, you are not only breaking the strict aliasing rule, but also alignment rules. You can't just take a memory address and interpret it as a pointer to a different type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The problem may be in the code that you are not showing us. Please provide a small, complete program that demonstrates the problem. For information about why that is important, and how to do it, see http://sscce.org.

Comment: Thanks. From that example, it is clear that @Kerrek and I both provide the correct answer. Please accept the one that is most useful to you by clicking the appropriate checkmark.

Comment: P.s. If you code on Linux, I recommend making [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) part of your daily routine. Running the above test program under valgrind detects this particular error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code,

```
for(unsigned int b = 0; b < effective_length; b++)
{
    sscanf(source.data() + (b * 2), "%02x", (unsigned int*) &destination[b]);
}
```

you seem to be writing an `unsigned int` at locations `destination`, `destination+1`, `destination+2`, &c. As you approach the final bytes of your `destination` buffer, you will write beyond its limit.

For the sake of example, let us assume that destination is a four-byte buffer, and that `sizeof (unsigned int)` is 4 in your environment.  Then each `sscanf` is writing four bytes.

The first iteration writes bytes 0, 1, 2, 3

The second iteratino writes bytes 1, 2, 3, 4

The third iteration writes bytes 2, 3, 4, 5

The final iteration writes bytes 3, 4, 5, 6

Since the buffer was only four bytes to start with, you have written beyond the end of your buffer. Boom.

---

**EDIT**

The minimum change required to avoid this particular bug follows:

```
for(unsigned int b = 0; b < effective_length; b++)
{
    unsigned int ui;
    sscanf(source.data() + (b * 2), "%02x", &ui);
    destination[b] = ui;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but I needed another pair of eyes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sscanf` will write an `unsigned int` into the memory location you give it. Typically, an unsigned int is 4 or 8 bytes long, while you only intend to provide 1 byte. So at the end you're running flat-out over the end of your dynamic array.

By the way, your code is very far removed from modern, idiomatic C++ - it's essentially just a glorified C mess. I strongly suggest rewriting it in the spirit of C++.

Comment: As a long-time C programmer, I take offense that you think that looks like C. :)

Comment: @Rob: MY sincerest apologies! It was truly a question of who to insult least :-)

Comment: How would you write it in "C++"?

Comment: No pointers, and use `std::string` to your advantage. For the core conversion I'd probably use `strtoul()` on the string-to-binary side, and lookup in a static array on the binary-to-array side. Anyway, you seem to have found a sufficient answer, so let's just leave it at that.

Comment: Nit: I think he is only trying to write one byte, not two. `destination[b]` advances by one byte per loop iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite the code to actually use C++ facilities (haven't tested it really, just an idea):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> string_to_binary(const std::string& source)
{
    static int nibbles[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    std::vector<unsigned char> retval;
    for (std::string::const_iterator it = source.begin(); it < source.end(); it += 2) {
        unsigned char v = 0;
        if (std::isxdigit(*it))
            v = nibbles[std::toupper(*it) - '0'] << 4;
        if (it + 1 < source.end() && std::isxdigit(*(it + 1)))
            v += nibbles[std::toupper(*(it + 1)) - '0'];
        retval.push_back(v);
    }
    return retval;
}

std::string binary_to_string(const std::vector<unsigned char>& source)
{
    static char syms[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); it++)
        ss << syms[((*it >> 4) & 0xf)] << syms[*it & 0xf];

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that from Kerrek SB above. Thanks for giving me an example, though. I'll definitely consider rewriting it in this fashion once time permits. (Thankfully, the class is in a shared library, so updating the code will be easy)