# Convert 3d array elements from hex to binary for a bmp

Tags: c++, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I was successful at reading pixel values out of a 24 bit 512x512 .bmp into a 3-D array. The following is the code i have for a test image called lena512.bmp.

```
...snip ...
FILE *fptr;

int i, j, k;
char *filename = "lena512.bmp";
//char *filename2 = "anotherimage.bmp"; 
//ofstream myfile;
unsigned char databuff[512][512][3];


BmpFileHeader fheader;
BmpInfoHeader iheader;

printf("sizeof: fheader: %d   iheader: %d\n\n", sizeof(fheader),
       sizeof(iheader));
if ((sizeof(fheader) != 14) || (sizeof(iheader) != 40)) {
    printf("Header structs are not properly packed\n");
    return 0;
}

if ((fptr = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Coulsn't open file %s for reading.\n", filename);
    return 1;
};
if (fread(&fheader, sizeof(fheader), 1, fptr) != 1) {
    printf("Couldn't read fheader.\n");
    return 0;
}
if (fread(&iheader, sizeof(iheader), 1, fptr) != 1) {
    printf("Couldn't read iheader.\n");
    return 0;
}
printf("           fheader.type = %04x \n", fheader.type);
printf("           fheader.size = %u   \n", fheader.size);
printf("      fheader.reserved1 = %u   \n", fheader.reserved1);
printf("      fheader.reserved2 = %u   \n", fheader.reserved2);
printf("         fheader.offset = %u   \n", fheader.offset);
printf("           iheader.size = %u   \n", iheader.size);
printf("          iheader.width = %u   \n", iheader.width);
printf("         iheader.height = %u   \n", iheader.height);
printf("         iheader.planes = %u   \n", iheader.planes);
printf("           iheader.bits = %u   \n", iheader.bits);
printf("    iheader.compression = %u   \n", iheader.compression);
printf("      iheader.imagesize = %u   \n", iheader.imagesize);
printf("    iheader.xresolution = %u   \n", iheader.xresolution);
printf("    iheader.yresolution = %u   \n", iheader.yresolution);
printf("        iheader.ncolors = %u   \n", iheader.ncolors);
printf("iheader.importantcolors = %u   \n", iheader.importantcolors);
printf("\n");


if ((iheader.height != 512) || (iheader.width != 512) || (iheader.bits != 24)) {
    printf("This only works for 512x512 24-color bitmaps\n");
    return 0;
}
if (fheader.offset != 54) {
    printf("This only works if the offset is equal to 54\n");
    return 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < iheader.height; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < iheader.width; j++) {
        if (fread(&databuff[i][j][0], 3, 1, fptr) != 1) {
            printf("Couldn't read colors for element [%d][%d]\n", i, j);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
//myfile.open("lena512bmp_24bit.txt");
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { /* This should only give you the first row */
    printf("Row %2d:\n", i);
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) { /* look at the first element on each row */
        printf("  ");
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    printf("%02x ", databuff[i][j][k]);
    cout << databuff[i][j][k];

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
//myfile.close();
fclose(fptr);
 return 0;
```

I also include a header called `bmp_headers.h` to this fil, which is not quite relevant to the question that I'm about to ask.
The output here is `37 51 9E` (displayed in hex) since my `for` loops just consider the first 3 elements of the first row (after the first 54 bytes of image headers). The output to the 512x512 image is consistent with the values displayed in the hex-editor for the same image. I wish to convert every element in this array into a string of binary characters and display them. (i.e `37 51 9E` ==> `00110111  01010001 10011110`).
If I understand correctly I would have to convert this array into string, then into hex and then into a string of binary. Is there an easier way to do this? I find myself to be slightly confused right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 3 bytes for the bit depth: RGB

Comment: Aha okay, just curious. Anyway, that's not important, as 90% of the question, if I understand correctly (honestly, I'm not trying to be offensive). @user1227372, are you asking how to convert a hex number stored in a char-array to a binary char-array?

Comment: I just thought that i would be a convenient way to represent it . I could have chosen a 2-D array as well but i just thought this might work and it did.

Comment: But a 2-D array , i thought would be a better way to represent an 8-bit greyscale image as opposed to a 24 bit RGB image.

Comment: @user12273722, if you're just trying to convert hex to binary numbers stored in C strings, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363774/c-converting-binary-data-to-a-hex-string-and-back) could help then?

Comment: Using scanf and sprintf is not really C++-sy, and a bit overkill. To convert any number to binary you just need to divide the number by two until it reaches 0, and store the remainder as the binary values.

Comment: @Eitan : Yes somewhat. My idea was to first convert every element(unsigned char) as a string ( a hex string) , and then convert that string into a binary string". I might be asking you the same question again but i truly am a novice at c++ but i am a quick learner at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you question is tagged C++ so here's how to do it in C++:

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string ToBinary(T value)
{
    std::stringstream sstream;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        sstream << static_cast<char>((value % 2) + 48);
        value /= 2;
    }
    std::string result = sstream.str();
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { /* This should only give you the first row */
    std::cout << "Row " << i << std::endl;
    for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) { /* look at the first element on each row */
        std::cout << "  ";
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            std::cout << ToBinary(databuff[i][j][k]);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```