# How to convert stringified binary (a string of "1"s and "0") to a corresponding char string

Tags: c, string, binary, arduino, ascii

Given a stringified binary representation, I would like to convert it back to real binary which will be treated as chars.  For example, the string `01000001 01000010 01000011 01000001` should be converted to "ABCA", since ASCII of 'A' is 65 which is binary `01000001`, and so on.

The function for the conversion in the opposite direction is as follows:

```
String getBinary(String str) {
    String message = str;
    int length = message.length();
    String binaryNumber = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        char c = message.charAt(i);
        binaryNumber = binaryNumber + String(c, BIN) + " ";
    }

    return binaryNumber;
}
```

I have tried many things from C++, C and Java (and converted it to 'Arduino code'), but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You should post code you tried to use for the conversion you want, rather than posting the code that works without any problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Converting binary data to a hex string and back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363774/c-converting-binary-data-to-a-hex-string-and-back)

Comment: @joeframbach: The OP is not talking about binary data, but about a character string like "11100101011" something, I suspect. So it's not really a dupe. To what this actually shall be converted I do not really get ...

Comment: No, it takes a string and outputs it in this stinrified binary format, where the ouput string contains only characters `1` and `0` representing the binary `1` and `0` in that bit

Comment: Why is this tagged as [tag:C]? It's most definitely not C code.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: I tagged it as C figuring that given that this is C-like: I thought it'd be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, though, honestly, I have not tested it:

```
String debinaryStringify(String source) {
    String result = "";
    int idxStart = 0;
    do {
        char val = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            val += ((source.charAt(idxStart+i) == '1') << (7-i)); // Trick: Assignment of an evaluation result
        }
        result.concat(val);
        idxStart = source.indexOf(' ') + 1;
    } while ( (idxStart > 0) && (idxStart < source.length() - 7) );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to work, Hello World = 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 = ÊØØÞÝ½É±, thanks for the explanation though...

Comment: Having this example at the outset would have been helpful, I think. Anyway, I adjusted the code.